# SQLite: copy fields from one table to another table using a condition

Tags: sqlite, insert

I matched many answers about copying data from one table to another. However how to use a clause in addition to the classical way:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (field1, field2) SELECT field1, field2 FROM T1;
```

I want to copy X fields from T1 to T2 but where T2.T1_id = T1.id.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO bottles (volume_id, container_id) SELECT volume_id, container_id FROM wines, bottles WHERE bottles.wine_id = wines.id
```

In fact, I want to move *volume_id, container_id* from wines to bottles, but for bottles corresponding to each wine.

Does I need an UPDATE instead ?

Something LIKE this is possible ?

```
INSERT INTO bottles (volume_id, container_id) VALUES (SELECT volume_id, container_id FROM wines, bottles WHERE bottles.wine_id = wines.id) WHERE bottles.wine_id = wines.id
```

Thanks !

**EDIT**:

*Example current data*:

```
table wines
-----------
id: 1
volume_id: 14
container_id:3
-
id: 2
volume_id: 15
container_id:4

table bottles
-------------
id: 1
wine_id: 1
-
id:2
wine_id: 1
-
id:3
wine_id: 2
```

*New wanted data*:

```
table wines
-----------
id: 1
...
-
id: 2
...

table bottles
-------------
id: 1
wine_id: 1
volume_id: 14
container_id:3
-
id:2
wine_id: 1
volume_id: 14
container_id:3
-
id:3
wine_id: 2
volume_id: 15
container_id:4
```

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: OK C.L, I added some example data.

Comment: OK. It works with the other thread answer.